# Upload file via Channel API

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I read the article which talk about Blobstore (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/).

I would to know if I can use Channel API to send a file, and if it's possible, how.

Answer (score 1):

The Channel API is designed to send text. So instead of sending a file via the Channel API, you would send a pointer to the file for the client to download. The pointer may be a datastore key, a blobstore key, a URL etc - depends on your backend really.